# What's the preferred way to create a jQuery object with attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

When creating jQuery objects I've used the following syntax lately, as described [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

```
var $el = $('<div/>', {
   class: 'class-1 class-2'
});
```

Safari 5.0.5 gives a syntax error at the point where I use the above construction.

Removing the second argument and adding classes with addClass removes the error, but seems rather unelegant.

How do you create your objects? I tried with attr({class: 'class-1'}), as well, but received the same syntax error.

Comment: If you put the word "class" in single or double quotes, it'll work fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `class`; it's a reserved word.

Use `className` instead:

```
var $el = $('<div/>', {
   className: 'class-1 class-2'
});
```

Comment: You can use "class" if you quote it.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks a lot. After more research I found this performance test for different element creation constructs: http://jsperf.com/create-element-with-attributes-jquery-1-4-object-vs-att/2 It seems the above syntax is not the best performance wise.

Answer (score 3):

Make the attribute name a string:

```
var $el = $('<div/>', {
    'class': 'class-1 class-2'
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/G7mwc/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Since `class` is a reserved word, you need to put it in quotes.

```
var $el = $('<div/>', {
   "class": 'class-1 class-2'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You get an error as `class` is a reserved keyword. You can use a string as identifier when a property name is a reserved keyword:

```
var $el = $('<div/>', {
   'class': 'class-1 class-2'
});
```